# How do I make a Window invisible while still having a taskbar icon?

Tags: windows, winapi

For reasons involving stitching a two applications into a single application (with two processes), I need to make the initial Window invisible to the user, while continuing to have an Icon in in the taskbar (where I will use a Win7 API to paint a different preview).

1. I've tried turning it invisible, but this removes the icon from the taskbar.
2. The Windows manager prevents me from moving it off screen (unless I subclass and ignore Move).
3. Setting the opacity to zero and hittest to false removes the icon from the taskbar.

I've hit a brick wall. Any other suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks,
Erick

Comment: For reasons involving malware this is highly discouraged... hence why Microsoft has gone out of their way to make this difficult.

Comment: Have you tried setting the window's dimensions to 0x0?

Comment: Mgetz - I totally understand, but I'm hoping to find a way around it.

Comment: Remy - I tried that - no luck.

Comment: Why don't you keep the window minimized